# Migrating to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0 for App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm currently trying to migrate from `Cloud Endpoints 1.0` to `Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0`.

I've followed the steps outlined here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating?authuser=0

In my `build.gradle` I've replaced:

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.42'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.42'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.0-beta.5'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

And in `web.xml` I've replaced `SystemServiceServlet` with `EndpointsServlet` and `/_ah/spi/*` with `/_ah/api/*`.

However on compile, I get the following error:

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':myapp_backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> > There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: web.xml must have 1 (found:0) SystemServiceServlet servlet
> ```

Am I missing something?

Edit, as requested by @saiyr, here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    // AppEngine
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.42'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    //  Cloud Endpoints
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.42'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.42'

    // Cloud Endpoints Frameworks
    // compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.0-beta.7'
    // compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    // Project
    compile files('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.9'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

**There is now a guide detailing the transition process here:** https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md

And here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android

Comment: No, you aren't missing anything. The Gradle App Engine plugin has not yet been updated to use the beta library, unfortunately. What build task are you using?

Comment: @saiyr Damn, all I'm trying to do is use `Firebase Auth` now mentioned on the [Cloud Endpoints landing page](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) but it seems in this [recent Google Cloud Platform Blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/09/manage-your-APIs-with-Google-Cloud-Endpoints.html) it's only for the new beta and that's why I'm trying to migrate across. I use Gradle's `appengineUpdate` task to build and deploy my backend. Is my assumption correct I have to migrate from `Cloud Endpoints 1.0` to `Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0` to use `Firebase Auth`?

Comment: Yes, you need to use 2.0. It surprises me that `gradle appengineUpdate` would trigger the `appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs` task. Is this an Android Studio file? Can you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: The appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs only runs automatically when configured in your build.gradle file. The latest release of the plugin (1.9.42) doesn't handle the newest version of endpoints at the moment. Filed an issue here for tracking : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/issues/261

Comment: @saiyr, correct, this is using Android Studio. I've edited my post with my `build.gradle` file (I've reverted back to `1.0` by commenting out `2.0`). Note the error I copied was also from when gradle syncs. As you work on endpoints, any idea when support for `2.0` will be released? I'm not sure how to upgrade without proper gradle support. PS thank you for your work!

Comment: @loosebazooka Seems so. Edit: Hang on, do you work on the appengine gradle plugin? Could you please tell me when you think support for `2.0` will be released? I purely want to migrate to `2.0` for now to use Firebase Auth with endpoints. This seems like the correct approach Google is hoping devs take. PS thank you for your work too!

Comment: I don't get it. Is cloud endpoints v2 not ever going to be supported on Android Studio?

Comment: @BlueBoy it is now! See my answer below, or https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New plugin now available, transition guide:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md

(or https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android)

Don't forget to also follow the migration guide:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating?authuser=0

Comment: After doing chnages as suggested i am getting this error Error:Could not find com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.  From where can i download the plugin?

Comment: @RafiqAhmad what repositories do you have set? If may be better to post your gradle files as a new question and link to them here and I will have a look.

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562977/migrating-google-cloud-endpoints-to-version-v2 let me know what am i doing wrong with migration.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Gradle plugin is in the progress of being updated, for now you need to comment out/delete the `endpoints` fragment so that client libraries aren't generated on build. Then, if you need to generate client libraries, do it [manually](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/generate-client-libraries-android) for now.

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit on this answer.?I got email from cloud support Framework v1 deprecated from aug 2.

Comment: @RafiqAhmad there is now a guide detailing the transition process here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md

Comment: @gbhail thanks for the response i will look and get back to you if it worked or not

Answer (score -2):

Hi don't know if you fixed it already but this solved my problem

compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.0-beta.9'