# Error Generating Client Libraries for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks 2.0

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-endpoints

I am building a `Google App Engine` app along with `Firebase` and I would like to use the newest features of `Google cloud endpoints` (version 2) such as user authentication and support for `Firebase` read/writes which is my main concern.

After going through the official documentation I am stuck at generating the client API libraries...
Apparently as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342980/migrating-to-cloud-endpoints-frameworks-2-0-for-app-engine) it should be done manually as Android Studio does not support the function at this moment (even after updating the relevant files as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/set-up-environment)) it produces this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':endpointVag:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
>   There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: web.xml must have 1 (found:0) SystemServiceServlet servlet

Following the instructions from [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/generate-client-libraries-android) and after running this command:

```
C:\android_project_path\endpoints-framework-tools-2.0.0-beta.11\bin>endpoints-framework-tools.bat get-client-lib --war=C:\android_project_path\src\main\webapp -l java -bs gradle com.somename.project.endpoints.MyEndpoint
```

I get the following error :

```
Error: com.somename.project.endpoints.MyEndpoint
```

Any suggestions what is going on here or **how to properly generate the client libraries manually??**

Thanks!

Edit, I am attaching the contents of my web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.somename.project.endpoints.MyEndpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>restricted</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
        <param-value>myproject</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
        <param-value>myproject.appspot.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: can you please post your web.xml?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer added as requested

Comment: Hi George. Can you try the GA version [2.0.0](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/endpoints/endpoints-framework-tools/2.0.0/endpoints-framework-tools-2.0.0.zip) tools instead? Is that the only line of output you get?

Comment: Any updated answers to this question?version 1 deprecated from aug 2

Comment: @RafiqAhmad Assuming that you are using windows and gradle you can navigate to the main folder of your project and the easiest way is to run the following command: `gradlew endpointsClientLibs` you can also refer to the latest documentation from the Google team [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/generate-client-libraries-android)

Comment: @GiorgosS. Thanks for the response i solved it.

Comment: @RafiqAhmad No problem happy to help, consider posting your solution as well to help others that may have the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is your issue:

```
--war=C:\android_project_path\src\main\webapp
```

The `--war` parameter must point to the root of the exploded WAR directory of your compiled app. You're pointing it to the 'webapp' folder of your app's source. You'll notice the example [given in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/generate-client-libraries-android) your referenced is `target/echo-1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

To be sure I've tested this with a sample app on a Linux and Windows system (using the latest `endpoints-frameworks-tools` [version 2.0.3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.endpoints%7Cendpoints-framework-tools%7C2.0.3%7Cjar)) and the client libs were generated without problems.

Comment: I changed the web.xml via Android Studio but the gradle run automatically and the build failed (as expected).  Now the exploded-app directory is gone...can you please explain how to build the backend manually (via cmd) without reverting to endpoints version1 ? (If there is no other way I would have to revert to endpoints v1 , re-build using Android studio and then change the web.xml in the exploded directory which will probably work..)

Comment: Scratch the above, I will mark you answer as correct because it enabled me to go further as your observation was correct. I used android studio and disabled the tasks that were exporting,installing etc the client libraries and then run the backend which created the explode-app folder. Running the manual command from that point generated the libraries succesfully.

Answer (score -1):

can you please replace the entry

```
 <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
```

with

```
<servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
```

and try to generate the client libs again?

Comment: Yes but according to this <https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating>  that would imply that I am using version 1.0 correct? I would like to use version 2.0 of Cloud Endpoints Java Framework.

Comment: yes, correct. So I would guess that the plugin for generating the Client libs does not support Version 2.

Comment: Yeap that seems to be the case as stated above, the issue here is why the manual instructions produce an error as well..

Comment: just one last comment: did you try a different beta version to generate the client libs? I can see that you are using beta 11 but at https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/generate-client-libraries-android I can see that they are using beta 7.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Michael, yes I have tried different beta version as well unfortunately to no avail. 
Did you try to replicate the issue with beta 7 and it worked?

Comment: no, I just saw the difference between the docs and your description. I am still using Version 1 because I do not want to run on Flex Environment

Comment: Just to clarify, cloud endpoints frameworks is not recommended for Flex environment. For App engine standard, endpoints frameworks is recommended to be used and version 2 is upgrading version 1 so it can be used instead. To help you understand better have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks-extensible-service-proxy#cloud_endpoints_frameworks)

Comment: Downvoting as this is a question, not an answer.