# Migrating Google cloud endpoints to version v2

Tags: android-studio, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have referred this link on stack overflow still unable to migrate to version v2.

[Link Referred from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342980/migrating-to-cloud-endpoints-frameworks-2-0-for-app-engine)

After doing changes as suggested in the below link i am getting this error.

[Link Referred](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md)

> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Here is my project level gradle file

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8'
        classpath "com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> App level build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.migrationv2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
    endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.21.0'
}
```

> Backend build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
//    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.42'
//    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.42'
//    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.42'
//    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-framework', version: '+'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
}


endpointsServer {
    // Endpoints Framework Plugin server-side configuration
    hostname = "xxx.appspot.com"
}
//appengine {
//    downloadSdk = true
//    appcfg {
//        oauth2 = true
//    }
//    endpoints {
//        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
//        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
//    }
//}
```

Please let me know what am i doing wrong in this migration any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full samples are available on: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android

Replace with your project level `build.gradle`, removing `google()` as a repository with this:

> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Your app level `build.gradle` is missing a `buildscript`. It needs to look something like this.

> app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Endpoints Frameworks Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.migration.endpoints.app'
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // androidTestCompile compiles instrumentation tests written using Espresso
    // used by Firebase Test Lab
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // V2: Endpoints Framework v2 migration
    endpointsServer project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'endpoints')
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.22.0'
}
```

I also have some extra dependencies in my backend level `build.gradle` based on:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-endpoints-frameworks-plugin

> backend/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

// V2: Apply new App Engine and Endpoints Framework server plugins
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    // AppEngine
    compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk', version: '+'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    //  Cloud Endpoints Framework
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-framework', version: '+'
    compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-management-control-appengine', version: '+'
    compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-framework-auth', version: '+'
}

endpointsServer {
  // Endpoints Framework Plugin server-side configuration
  hostname = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com"
}
```

These provided above are not direct representations of what I have, but are a mix and match from various Google documentation sources.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped internally i was havng gradle issue also solved it.one more question is we need to deploy using command line for future deployments?

Comment: In Android Studio, you can select the Gradle tab in the right column, and under your backend tasks, you can double click `appengineDeploy` to deploy your module. That's how I do it now.

Comment: How to upload cron servelets if i deploy with my endpoints its giving 500 internal server error.Any idea about cron servelets?

Comment: @RafiqAhmad There's a gradle task `appengineDeployCron` you need to run to deploy cron tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need the `google()` line in your repositories, which you currently have twice.